# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the carousel on my webpage as follows

```
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                    <img src="/public/images/Lighthouse.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="/public/images/Lighthouse.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="/public/images/Lighthouse.jpg">
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!--End of Carousel-->
```

I would like it to remain responsive, which at present it is, the picture adjusts as the screen gets smaller. However the carousel fills the whole page (Width) and I would like to make it smaller and have it sit in the center of the page. I have given a width for .carousel but this seems to effect the responsiveness.

Does anyone know how to customize this plugin or have done this in the past

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you can put this on jsfiddle?

Comment: its ok now, ive solved it, added a media query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

media Query solves this issue as I had given the carousel a width

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .carousel {
  width: 100%;
  }
 }
```

Comment: wondering does it put the arrows intact along with the image even as you resize? Because my case was arrows going out and in while the page resizing occurs. Did it solve it?

Comment: From memory i think it all resizes, if not just adjust the arrows as necessary and pop it into the same media query

Answer (score 0):

where and how to add this `@media (max-width:600px) {
                        .carousel {
                        width: 100%;
                        }
                        }` instruction

Comment: depends on how you have your CSS structure set out, but just put it at the bottom of your main stylesheet